# How to increase storage size in pouchDB

Tags: angular, ionic3, indexeddb, pouchdb, typescript2.0

I am developing ionic 3/angular 4 app using pouchDB with indexed db adapter. My query is how to increase indexed db size in pouchDB using ionic 3/angular 4 as my json size is 20mb which i want to store in db for offline application.

Any help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the typescript (type definition) for "pouchdb core" the size parameter has been left out. 
Until the typedefinition file is updated in future version you might want to add it yourself

around line 516 of index.d.ts (node_modules/@types/pouchdb-core/index.d.ts), inside the interface declaration.

from

```
interface LocalDatabaseConfiguration extends CommonDatabaseConfiguration {
    auto_compaction?: boolean;
    revs_limit?: number;
}
```

to

```
interface LocalDatabaseConfiguration extends CommonDatabaseConfiguration {
        auto_compaction?: boolean;
        revs_limit?: number;
        size?: number;
}
```

A pull request for this change has been provided but so far did not make it into the latest version

Answer (score 0):

For 20mb i think you are safe to go with most major browsers.

- Chromium based browsers will calculate based on available disk space and allow app to store up to 6% of available disk space which can be quite large. [chromium space calculation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_storage#temporary)
- Firefox have an initial 50mb limit and then asks for users permission if the your app needs more.
- Mobile Safari and IE have 50mb and 250mb hard limits respectively with very annoying need to request permissions from user intermittently.
  [see more information here](https://pouchdb.com/faq.html#data_limits)